# Inserting a dynamic tkinter variable into a function arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

How do you insert a dynamic tkinter variable into a function's arguments? I'm a newbie that just recently starting learning python.

Let's say I have a function with tkinter after() method that updates every second and that constantly change an integer variable value to my local time's second value. Then I want to put that variable into a function that does something like down here.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as tm

wdw = tk.Tk()
wdw.geometry('500x500')
insert = tk.IntVar() #defined the variable that will inserted to function something

def clock():
    scd= int(tm.strftime('%S')) #get the second local time
    insert.set(scd) # set the insert variable with the local time
    wdw.after(1000,clock) #update the variable scd every second

def something(val):
    u=val #set the wanted letter from the text below
    p=0
    q=0
    TXT= 'This is a text that will be rendered to the label below every 3 letter per second'
    while u < val+3:
        label=tk.Label(wdw,text=TXT[u],font="Courier",fg="red") #prints the needed letter
        label.place(x=17+p,y=17+q)
        p+=17 #translate by the x axis
        q+=17 #translate by the y axis
        u+=1 #cycle to the next letter

clock() #run the clock function to refresh the scd variable
something(insert.get()) #run the something function with the updated 'insert' variable
wdw.mainloop()
```

The problem with the code above is the variable `insert` is stuck and won't update every second, so I'm stuck with a window that only render a text that associated with the second I run the code.

How can I make the variable `insert` dynamic, so in a way that it would render different text depending with the second in my local time. Like it would render "Thi" during the first second, then render "his" during the second second, "is " during the third second, "s a" at fourth second, " a " at fifth second and so on.

Is there a function inside the tkinter that I wasn't aware of that could fix the problem, or is it the way python just can't update a variable dynamically? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide a better example of what you expect?

Comment: The `while` loop in the `something()` function is preventing `mainloop()` from running (which interfers with `after()`'s execution).

Comment: @CoolCloud  If my local time second is 1, I want to print the letter 1st to 3rd. if the second is 2 I want to print the letter 2nd to 4th. If it is 3, print letter 3rd to 5th, and so on.

Comment: @martineau well that's weird, the while loop should've stopped after u=val+3 and move on to other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trigger the something function from the clock function. Then it will run every second. Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as tm

wdw = tk.Tk()
wdw.geometry('500x500')
insert = tk.IntVar() #defined the variable that will inserted to function something

def clock():
    scd= int(tm.strftime('%S')) #get the second local time
    insert.set(scd) # set the insert variable with the local time
    wdw.after(1000,clock) #update the variable scd every second
    something() #run the something function with the updated 'insert' variable

def something():
    val=insert.get() #set the wanted letter from the text below
    u=val #set the wanted letter from the text below
    p=0
    q=0
    TXT= 'This is a text that will be rendered to the label below every 3 letter per second'
    while u < val+3:
        label=tk.Label(wdw,text=TXT[u],font="Courier",fg="red") #prints the needed letter
        label.place(x=17+p,y=17+q)
        p+=17 #translate by the x axis
        q+=17 #translate by the y axis
        u+=1 #cycle to the next letter

clock() #run the clock function to refresh the scd variable
wdw.mainloop()
```

Comment: Holy shit thanks, this is the one that I need. I thought that it would be updated anyway if I put it outside the clock function.